# Android and BroadcastReceiver for Email

Tags: android, uri, intentfilter

Is there in android an action for the broadcast receiver stimulated by an incoming email such as the uri `android.intent.action.CALL`  is stimulated by an incoming call?

Answer (score 3):

No. Email is not part of the operating system.

Comment: And I can do for to do this ??

Comment: @user989377: That is not a valid English sentence.

Comment: How can do to know when email is notified on the phone?

Comment: @user989377: You find the author of every email application for Android. You ask each one of them to add some sort of API to do this. You wait weeks, months, or years for them to implement this. You then realize that they each implemented it differently. So you contact all of them again, asking them to honor some standard that you devise. You then wait weeks, months, or years for them to implement the standard.

Comment: I want only gmail and I want to know only when the phone notify a new gmail's email...it's possible ? :)

Comment: @user989377: There is no documented and supported API for Gmail.

Comment: Is the answer provided by gnugu no longer valid?

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/6sBMKpnraBw

Comment: Also, would this be of any help?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/

It might not get everything you want but maybe you could detect when the unread inbox count changes.

Comment: @gonzobrains: "Is the answer provided by gnugu no longer valid?" -- that answer was from 2009. It was never a documented and supported feature of Gmail, and it has been blocked for quite some time (http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/08/gmail-gone-risk-undocumented-apis.html). The newer Gmail *has* a documented API, per the link in your second comment, but only for label information.

Comment: I had a feeling it wouldn't be valid considering it was from 2009. I don't know anything about the Labels API, but if I could monitor the Inbox label for changes in the unread message count that may be useful for my purposes.  But this is a workaround because obviously unread count decreases each time the user reads an unread message.